# How to sort nested list with different priority of characters in a single element in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested-lists

Sorry for not being able to come out with a good title.

I have a list:

```
some_list = [[X, '4x01'], [X, '3x02'], [X, '4x02'], [X, '3x01']]
```

where `X` is something I don't care.

I want to sort the second element in the list with the following priorities:

1. The first character in descending order.
2. The last 2 characters in ascending order.

The final output should be:

```
some_list = [[X, '4x01'], [X, '4x02'], [X, '3x01'], [X, '3x02']]
```

**Note**: The solution that gives the incorrect answer is:

```
output = sorted(some_list, key=lambda lis: lis[3], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use a composite key as @Amber did. However, that approach doesn't always work: for example, it would fail if both components were two characters long (since the `-ord(x[1][0])` trick would no longer work).

Here is a more general solution:

```
In [15]: X = None

In [16]: some_list = [[X, '4x01'], [X, '3x02'], [X, '4x02'], [X, '3x01']]

In [17]: l = sorted(some_list, key=lambda (x,y):y[-2:])

In [18]: l = sorted(l, key=lambda (x,y):y[:1], reverse=True)

In [19]: l
Out[19]: [[None, '4x01'], [None, '4x02'], [None, '3x01'], [None, '3x02']]
```

It sorts the list one criterion at a time, and makes use of the fact that Python's sort is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

An even more general approach is to provide a comparator:

```
def f((x1,y1), (x2,y2)):
    c = cmp(y1[:1], y2[:1])
    if c != 0: return -c
    return cmp(y1[-2:], y2[-2:])
```

This can be used as follows:

```
In [39]: sorted(some_list, cmp=f)
Out[39]: [[None, '4x01'], [None, '4x02'], [None, '3x01'], [None, '3x02']]
```

Comment: A better option if you get to this point would probably be to just write a comparison function. That would prevent you from having to sort the list twice (a potentially expensive operation if the list is large).

Comment: @Amber: Fair point. Still, this is a useful technique worth knowing about.

Comment: Please help me understand your argument. If it were two characters long, won't `-ord(x[1][:1])` do the trick instead?

Comment: @elwc: I assume you mean `-ord(x[1][:2])`. This will raise an exception because `ord()` can only be applied to a single-character string. The `-ord(...)` trick relies on `...` being exactly one character long.

Comment: Good assumption you made. No wonder I'm not getting an error. And about the comparison function @Amber mentioned, what is that?

Comment: @elwc see here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key

Comment: That is certainly high class way of doing it. Difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 6):

```
output = sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: (-ord(x[1][0]), x[1][-2:]))
```

Example run (defining X as `None` just so I can copy-paste your list definition):

```
>>> X = None
>>> some_list = [[X, '4x01'], [X, '3x02'], [X, '4x02'], [X, '3x01']]
>>> output = sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: (-ord(x[1][0]), x[1][-2:]))
>>> output
[[None, '4x01'], [None, '4x02'], [None, '3x01'], [None, '3x02']]
```

Comment: This is right on the mark. I will never arrive to this answer despite hours of thinking. Thanks

Comment: Python one-liners are so nice. You can do so much and still - in contrast to, e.g., Perl, they are still readable.